# intel gpu and nvidia swaping each other during game

Tags: drivers, gpu, nvidia-graphics-card, intel-graphics

Laptop dell g5 5587.
Integrated gpu uhd 630 and discrete 1050 ti mobile.
Have latest drivers and updates windows 10.
Via Nvidia Control Panel I've set in which programs to use nvidia gpu.
Even set "Maximum perfomance" in intel graph settings in "Power"(battery) when plugged in.
Used DDU in safe mode to reinstall drivers.
Via msconfig I have disabled all services except Microsoft and then enabled only nvidia services. Highest temp was 86* for gpu.
The issue didn't disappear. I still have carrousels while game is running Like for 1 minutes the game use intel gou and i got lags and the next 1 minute it's all smooth cause it's running on nvidia gpu. Here u can see screens from task manager and usage of gpus - i get also lags outside the game when intel gpu is on high usage. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1WsId7ds_-eqnah4jausqycgjMLux3qmE
nvidia gpu wasn't overloaded or overheated

Answer (score 0):

Disable your (intel) on-board video via your BIOS. If you don't how to do that. I suggest looking up videos on how to do that or calling DELL and asking the how it's done for your specific laptop.

> i couldn't regulate brightness and night-light (win 10 option making screen bit orange) didn't work.

You can control this in the nvidia software settings. Put it this way. Your nvidia chip and software can do ANYTHING your on-board video can do.

Comment: I didn't disable it via bios. But I did it via device manager, and got issues - i couldn't regulate brightness and night-light (win 10 option making screen bit orange) didn't work. Nvidia sup told me that manufacturer of laptops with 2 cards integrate some functionality in intel graph card - that wont be accessible with disabled card. OS and games are on ssd (forgot to mention this)

Comment: Try using the Nvidia software to select the high performance mode (Nvidia). It shouldn't change modes (to Intel) regardless of the per program settings.

Comment: I downloaded dell support assistant and got bios update despite windows update didn't suggest me that update. The issue was resolved (cards don't change each other while playing but now I get stable lags each few seconds will reinstal game if won't help - reinstal display drivers).

Comment: Windows update has nothing to do with bios update.

Comment: Honestly, this question is out of my depth, i've never heard of a laptop using 2 different video cards at once. I don't even understand how this is possible. You either are using 1 or the other. If your computer somehow is switching between the 2 cards. THIS IS A HUGE BUG that needs to be addressed with DELL. In 20 years i've never once experienced this or heard that such a thing is possible. And to be perfectly honest, I think your lack of computer knowledge is hindering me from understanding what exactly is going on here.